# An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
Can not upgrade

An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool.

I cant update ubuntu from 18.10 to 20.04

Comment: have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208109/how-to-upgrade-from-18-10-to-19-10-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do it in sequence?...go from Cosmic..to Disco...then from Disco to Eoan...from Eoan to Focal?....(and eventually from Focal to Groovy [Gorilla] and then to Hirsute [Hippopotamus]) just a suggestion. Yeah it might take a long time depending on your hardware etc?...but at least you'll be up-to-date!!